# php ellipsis, entire words for start and end with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Trying to create an ellipsis showing only part of string first and rest of string after click function.

Found many tutorials to create the ellispis function but tried a long while how to get the entire word from the end part.

I've tried to do it like this

```
<?php

    $text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.";
    //     123456789
    echo substr($text,0,9); // result: "Lorem ips"
    echo '<hr>';

    $start = substr($text,0,9);
    // now this preg_replace() is awesome cause its only returning the entire word
    echo preg_replace('/\w+$/','',$start); //result: "Lorem"

    echo '<hr>';
    echo substr($text,9,strlen($text)); //result:  "um dolor sit amet."

    // now how should this preg_replace be to get result "ipsum dolor sit amet."

?>
```

So the question is: how should this `preg_replace()` be used to get result `"ipsum dolor sit amet."`.

I've tried to change arround things like `preg_replace('/\$+w/','',$start);` but I have no idea how to write that regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/^\w+\s/','',$text)
```

Comment: awesome thank you! have you got any links or resources to learn how to write those regexes?

Comment: @caramba: To learn regex, this is one of the best tutorials: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorbos answer is exactly right on my question. As my question was not real clear I had to change the answer to get the result I needed like this. The problem was that the string might start from anywhere (given position). So I still have no idea if this is possible to solve with preg_replace()

This gives me the same result:

```
$count=9;
$rest = substr($text,$count,strlen($text));
while( substr($rest, 0,1)!=' ' ) {
    $rest = substr($text,$count,strlen($text));
    $count--;
}
echo $rest;
```

If anyone has a better solution feel free to post.
Thank you!